# Send custom field value to email

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, contact-form, contact-form-7

I created custom post type named Emails, and added a custom field using advanced custom fields plugin to one post inside the custom post type called email footer, the field is image field that is supposed to show at the bottom of each automatic email going out of the website.

the current code I'm using

```
function wpcf7ev_verify_email_address2( $wpcf7_form ){
     $email_footer = '<html>
<body style="color:#000000;">
<div style="font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:20px;">
Regards,
<br/>

$email_footer .= '<img src="http://mysite.col/footer_image.jpg" width="100%"  alt=""/>
</div>';
$email_footer .='<div style="display:none;">'.generateRandomString().
'</div></body>
</html>
';
```

the code is working, it displays the image with this url at the bottom: http://mysite.col/footer_image.jpg

but I don't want hardcoded, I want to be able to modify it with the custom field I created

I looked at ACF documentation and found this, but I don't know how to use it to still show that exact field on custom post type I created:

```
<?php 

$image = get_field('image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've outlined from the ACF documentation tells you how to get the image from an ACF field using Image (with type array).

If we were to implement this into your function, we'd have to reference the image from the page somewhere. Without knowing how you're calling this there are a couple of ways you could embed it.

The first way, we pass it through to the function called on the page, like so...

```
wpcf7ev_verify_email_address2(get_field('image'));
```

and then update your function like so...

```
function wpcf7ev_verify_email_address2($image, $wpcf7_form)
{
    $email_footer = '<div style="font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:20px;">Regards,<br/>';
    // get the image from the passed in image function.
    $email_footer .= '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" width="100%"  alt="' . $image['alt'] . '"/></div>';
    $email_footer .='<div style="display:none;">' . generateRandomString() . '</div>';
}
```

Or, the second way, if you are calling the function to modify an action or something, you'd have to get the image from whichever page ID / options page it is assigned to in your ACVF settings. This would make your function look a little like this:

```
function wpcf7ev_verify_email_address2($wpcf7_form)
{
    // get image acf field from page with id 1
    $image = get_field('image', 1);

    // or get image from acf field on options page
    // $image = get_field('image', 'options');

    $email_footer = '<div style="font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:20px;">Regards,<br/>';
    $email_footer .= '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" width="100%"  alt="' . $image['alt'] . '"/></div>';
    $email_footer .='<div style="display:none;">' . generateRandomString() . '</div>';
}
```

All of the above is presuming that your function is working as intended, with you needing help grabbing the ACF field, and the image is uploaded. You can wrap your declarations of get_field in `if` statements if required.